# Hadoop and Object Reuse, Why?

Tags: java, performance, hadoop

In Hadoop, [objects passed to reducers are reused](http://wikidoop.com/wiki/Hadoop/ObjectReuse). This is extremely surprising and hard to track down if you're not expecting it. Furthermore, the [original tracker for this "feature"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-2399) doesn't offer any evidence that this change actually improved performance (unless I missed it).

> It would speed up the system substantially if we reused the keys and values [...] but I think it is worth doing.

This seems completely counter to this [very popular answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149569/9346). Is there some credence to the Hadoop developer's claim? Is there something "special" about Hadoop that would invalidate the notion of object creation being cheap?

Comment: I asked this exact same question of an expert from one of the main Hadoop consulting firms, and he just kept asserting it was necessary. I generally don't like party-line answers like that, but  I was willing to play along at the time.

Comment: @RobY you should convert you comment to an answer...

Comment: lol thanks, but like his response, I don't think mine is actually an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the article you linked, it says

> Running a simple unit test on your desktop machine should highlight
>   that creating 1x10^6 new String objects with random byte content is
>   slower than using a single Text object and calling the set method to
>   configure the underlying byte contents

Well, that is self-evident. Creating a million new strings is always going to be slower than using a StringBuilder to manipulate a single string; everyone knows that.   But this may be a straw man; last time I checked, you still needed an individual string for each key in a collection.

If his argument is that allocating a million new strings to make a copy of the collection is expensive, well, yes it is.  Strings are reference types, after all; you could just store references to the original strings.

I guess we'll have to wait for him to complete his benchmarks.

Comment: The problem is that my simple unit test case shows 0 difference. The JIT seems reasonably smart to not copy if it doesn't need to. Besides 1M strings is much too small of a sample given my test created 6M+ in under 10s. I double we'll ever see a completed benchmark since this has been in Hadoop for nearly two years now.